# jQuery AJAX post to https web api action via cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, post, cross-domain

I have an azure website with a page that needs to post a form with sensitive information to service on a different domain, which has a ssl security enabled on the service. It's an MVC web api with [RequireHttps] and cross domain requests enabled.

Is it wrong to post sensitive information with jQuery post via cross domain ? Is it why originally the CORS is disabled on the server so that nobody does this kind of operations ?
If this is ok to do, how can I secure the information passed with jQuery ajax?
[image]

jQuery call could be something like this :

```
function workIt()
{
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://foo.net/api/web/doStuff',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
                doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doing it over https is about as secure as you can get without skipping the browser completely. What exactly is your question? are you asking for better ways to secure your data? are you asking if this is an acceptable practice (which would be an opinion and not really welcome here)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to secure? the data being transmitted? the endpoint on the target server?

Comment: @KevinB, I guess the question is more about acceptable practice and about usage of SSL with jQuery call. Sensitive data is usually sent between browser and client with use of SSL. How does it apply in this scenario and how can it be done ?

Comment: umm... by simply using ssl. you don't need to do anything more than that. Any additional form of obfuscation would be easily undone, and is therefore unnecessary.

Comment: I guess my confusion is due to the fact that posting will be done to different domain. An ssl will be established between machine in Domain 2 and browser. How will posting to the Domain 1 machine be made secure ?

Comment: It works the same way as the ssl between domain 2 and the browser. Performing ajax works no different than simply requesting the page yourself in a separate browser tab, other than the cross origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it wrong to post sensitive information with jQuery post via cross domain ?

no

> Is it why originally the CORS is disabled on the server so that nobody does this kind of operations ?

I'm not sure what you mean by "originally." CORS is opt-in because many sites' security rely on the fact that their pages can't be read from a script running on another domain. This was the case before CORS existed, so in order to maintain backwards compatibility, CORS is designed to allow new sites to share data voluntarily, rather than suddenly breaking all old sites.

I should point out that simple, blind cross-domain POST has always been allowed--one could just set the `action` of a form to be a resource from another site. Here, you use CORS because you're consuming the data (right?). Additonally, this is not a simple request because of the content type.

> If this is ok to do, how can I secure the information passed with jQuery ajax?

There's not much to it. Your current code doesn't have any glaring red flags. One thing in particular that this code does right is that it posts the data as `application/json`, which mitigates CSRF.